# ffmpeg and opengl

Tags: opengl, ffmpeg

Any tutorials/exmaples or sample code available to convert opengl raw images (raw pixel data obtained from glReadPixels from an opengl 3d scene) into mp4 or avi format using ffmpeg libraries?

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I want to generate and stream the video dynamically from these images. Is this possible? Any examples/projects which do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am converting raw RGB image into avi video, but I am starting mencoder to do that. I am reading raw pixels using glReadPixels, and forward those data to a pipe, and the mencoder reads other end (btw I am on linux)

Because of such setup, it is easy to change parameters.

If you want to do it yourself, here is a (bit out of date) tutorial : [ffmpeg tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html)

**EDIT**

You are right. Here is their example : [ffmpeg example](http://drv.nu/ffmpeg/doxygen/api-example_8c-source.html)
You can get it by downloading ffmpeg source

Comment: Can I do the same with ffmpeg libraries? The tutorial examples do not show encoding raw data. Am I missing something?

Comment: May be I wasn't clear in my question. Can I generate these videos and stream them dynamcially (with or without ffmpeg?)

Comment: @John Qualis If I understand you correctly, you want to grab the screen real-time, and stream it through the network. In that case, search for open source video streaming projects (for example the VLC player)

Comment: Yup. I can grab opengl 3D scenes as raw pixel data. I want to convert the raw data to video in real time and stream. Any other examples/projects?

Comment: I am trying just that. But I am a newbie.